# ¿Cómo mostrar por valor de GET en URL un solo resultado?

Tags: php, json, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente archivo PHP:

```
<?php
// Parsing this spreadsheet: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=1Hz_7IIaBLqORWrmfXsJ3c4ycOBiIR0EQxHHptnO6mtA&hl=en&output=html
$url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Hz_7IIaBLqORWrmfXsJ3c4ycOBiIR0EQxHHptnO6mtA/od6/public/values?alt=json';
$file= file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($file);
$rows = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'};




if ( $_GET["orden"] ) {
  foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<p>';
    $orden = $row->{'gsx$orden'}->{'$t'};
    $cliente = $row->{'gsx$cliente'}->{'$t'};
    $activo = $row->{'gsx$activo'}->{'$t'};
    echo $orden . ' by ' . $cliente . '<br>' . $activo;
    echo '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es cuando ingreso a la URL `ejemplo.com/rma.php?orden=134` me dé los resultados de únicamente esa orden.

Comment: Falta que incluyas una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado y que indiques si tu código funciona o te devuelve error.

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo en código o usando el API de consultas de google?

Comment: no me devuelve error, el problema es que me lista todo lo que tengo en el documento online de google: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hz_7IIaBLqORWrmfXsJ3c4ycOBiIR0EQxHHptnO6mtA

ejemplo online: https://www.jvdistribuciones.net/rma.php?orden=134

quiero que me liste solo la orden 134

Comment: Espero que mi respuesta sea de ayuda y que la sugerencia que te hago te muestre una funcionalidad adicional que quizá no conocieras :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más sencilla para tu problema es comprobar si el valor de cada registro es el que estás buscando a través del parámetro GET para pasar al siguiente registro si no es el que estamos buscando:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/' .
  '1Hz_7IIaBLqORWrmfXsJ3c4ycOBiIR0EQxHHptnO6mtA/od6/public/values?' .
  'alt=json';
$file= file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($file);
$rows = $json->feed->entry;

if ( isset($_GET['orden']) ) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if ($row->{'gsx$orden'}->{'$t'} != $_GET['orden']) {
            continue;
        }
        $orden = $row->{'gsx$orden'}->{'$t'};
        $cliente = $row->{'gsx$cliente'}->{'$t'};
        $activo = $row->{'gsx$activo'}->{'$t'};
        echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($orden), ' by ',
          htmlspecialchars($cliente), '<br>',
          htmlspecialchars($activo), '</p>';
    }
}
```

---

La segunda solución, la que yo prefiero, es solicitar al API de google únicamente el registro cuyo campo `orden` sea el solicitado:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['orden']) && filter_var($_GET['orden'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    $url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/' .
      '1Hz_7IIaBLqORWrmfXsJ3c4ycOBiIR0EQxHHptnO6mtA/od6/public/values?' .
      'alt=json&sq=' . urlencode('orden=' . $_GET['orden']);
    $file= file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($file);
    if (isset($json->feed->entry)) {
        foreach($json->feed->entry as $row) {
            $orden = $row->{'gsx$orden'}->{'$t'};
            $cliente = $row->{'gsx$cliente'}->{'$t'};
            $activo = $row->{'gsx$activo'}->{'$t'};
            echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($orden), ' by ',
              htmlspecialchars($cliente), '<br>',
              htmlspecialchars($activo), '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>No hubo resultados</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Parámetros incorrectos</p>';
}
```